# Overloading of F# Measures

Tags: f#, overloading, measures

Consider the following F# code:

```
[<Measure>] type pixel
[<Measure>] type inch
[<Measure>] type dot
[<Measure>] type percentage

let scaleCalculation (finalSize:float<pixel>) (originalSize:float<pixel>) =
   finalSize/originalSize * 100.0<percentage>
```

(I realize I need to check originalSize for 0 but that's not really germaine to this question).

What I'd like is to overload this function to handle inches and dots per inch. I don't think there's any way to overload on the unit of measure but I just thought I'd see if anyone had any suggestions on this.

I know I could do this:

```
   let scaleCalculation (finalSize:float) (originalSize:float) =
      finalSize/originalSize * 100.0<percentage>
```

but then I lose checking on the measure of finalSize and originalSize.  I just want to insure that the measure of finalSize and originalSize are the same.

Any suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let scaleCalculation (finalSize:float<'u>) (originalSize:float<'u>) =
   finalSize/originalSize * 100.0<percentage>
```

[Units of Measure in F#: Part Four, Parameterized Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewkennedy/archive/2009/06/09/units-of-measure-in-f_2300_-part-four-parameterized-types.aspx)

Comment: Absolutely excellent.  I figured I'd need to use a generic somehow but hadn't quite got to trying out the code just yet.  Thanks Gradbot.  Hey are you on Google+ yet?

Comment: And I wish I could give you another upvote for that link. :-)

Comment: @Benjol--why did you modify that code?  I mean as far as I can tell you changed the generic 'a to 'u--I don't quite follow how that's improving the code.  Also, if you're going to change the letter of the generic parameter 'm would make more sense to me.  'm as in "Measure". :-)

Comment: @Onorio `'u` is consistent with the style used in fsharps source code.  I assume it stands for unit of measure.